# Show closest with spec. class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table, with repetitive tbody's exactly as shown below:

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td  class="icons_small" style="color:#fff; vertical-align:middle;"><!--Change color to white if their is attachment--><span class="task_attachment" title="View Attached Items">v</span></td>
            <td><span class="active">Task Name</span><br /><span style="vertical-align:middle;" class="icons_small">U</span><span class="contact_name tiny">Contact/Customer</span></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;" class="tiny"><span class="date_assigned" title="Date Assigned">13/12/2012</span><br /><div id="progressbar" value="50" title="Progress"></div></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;"  class="icons_small"><span class="edit_task" title="Edit Task">E</span></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;" class="icons_small"><span class="flag_task" title="Flag Task as Important">f</span></td>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle;" class="icons_small"><span class="set_reminder" title="Set Reminder">A</span></td>
            <td class="tiny" style="color:#333;"><span class="delete_task" title="Delete Task">Delete</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="attachment" >
            <td class="icons_small" style="vertical-align:middle;"><span class="attchement_type" title="Attachment">A</span></td>
            <td colspan="6" class="tiny attachment_details">SomeAttachment.pdf</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Using jquery, within each tbody, I hide the second tr (class="attachment"). I want to show this tr, when I click on the above tr's first td, which contains span(class="task_attachment"). However, i'm running into an all or nothing situation, the code below give's me no result, but i think it is closer to what i'm looking for.

```
       // Show attached files
              <script>
               $("tr.attachment").hide();
                   $("span.task_attachment").click(
                        function () {
                            $(this).closest("tr.attachment").show()
                        });
               });
            </script>
```

Anyone have any suggestion, or see anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).closest("tr").next().show();
```

Closest tests itself and up to the DOM tree. WHat you need is to select next element to the span's closest `tr`.

Comment: Well, haha I was playing around with that for the last 25min, trying to get it to work, thank your for fixing it within the  10 seconds.

Comment: the site makes me wait about 15minutes before it allows me to.
THanks again